Tell TS to not reduce intersection to never
I'm trying to create object switch for actions of model but when defining object with all the actions TS complains about mismatch of passed action to found method:

TS2345: Argument of type PActions is not assignable to parameter of type never
The intersection
ILine & ICurve & IStroke & IBegin & IMove & IClose
was reduced to never because property means has conflicting types in some constituents.
Type ILine is not assignable to type never

I know where it is coming from: property means defines action type and is different for each action, but I've tried to tell compiler that this is by design and he can rest assured that I've handled all types:
type Actions = {
  [R in PActions["means"]]: (action: Extract<PActions, { means: R }>) => void
};

Works fine, if I define action as any, but that's hacky.
I would like to define it without having to resort to any type if possible, does anyone know how?
Here is the actual implementation:
type Actions = {
  [R in PActions["means"]]: (action: Extract<PActions, { means: R }>) => void
};

interface ILine {
  means: 'line';
  args: {a:string};
}

interface ICurve {
  means: 'curve';
  args: {b:string};
}

export type PActions = ILine | ICurve;

export function ResolveAction(
  action: PActions,
): void {
  const objSwitch: Actions = {
    line: (action: ILine): void => {},
    curve: (action: ICurve): void => {},
  };

  if (!action.means) {
    (action as ILine).means = 'line'
  }

  if (!objSwitch[action.means]) {
    return;
  }

  // Can't really figure out a way to tell ts that based on the property name object is properly selected, and he
  // doesn't have to worry :<
  objSwitch[action.means](action);
}

I've also tried defining common parent and using it as action type, but it complained about not matching anything (no surprise).

Please [edit] the question to include a [mre]. Here's a TS Playground to get started based on the current information in your question.

You've got so much ... in there that gives so many errors you're not asking about. Instead of pseudocode, please [edit] to provide a [mre] that demonstrates what you're talking about.  Presumably this is a correlated unions issue as discussed in ms/TS#30581 and therefore probably fixable with generics as discussed in ms/TS#47109. But without an example I can play with easily, it's hard to get started.

(see prev comment and pls do the requested edit) I made random guesses about what to do with ... and get this playground link which shows how ms/TS#47109 applies to this example. Does it fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer or find a suitable duplicate. If not, what's missing?

Thank you, @jcalz, you were very close with your assumptions! Sorry for the messy example, I've removed all ... and here is tweaked playground if you want to post your answer, so I can mark it here

The problem you're running into here is that TypeScript does not directly support correlated unions as described in microsoft/TypeScript#30581. When you have a value action of a union type like PActions, TypeScript only keeps track of the type of that value, and not its identity.  So if you write a single expression with multiple utterances of action, then TypeScript can't tell the difference between that and the same expression with utterances of different values of the same type.  So when it analyzes
objSwitch[action.means](action);

It treats it the same as if you had written
objSwitch[action1.means](action2)

where action1 and action2 are both of type PActions. Obviously that would be unsafe, since action1 might be an ILine while action2 might be an ICurve. So TypeScript complains about this, even though the thing it worries about is impossible.

The recommended approach in such situations is to refactor to replace unions with generics, so that action is of a generic type, and TypeScript can follow the generic relationship between objSwitch[action.means] and action.  The technique is described in microsoft/TypeScript#47109, and involves writing operations in terms of a "base" mapping interface, mapped types over that interface, and generic indexes into those types.
For your example it looks like this. The base interface is
interface MeansArgsMap {
  line: { a: string };
  curve: { b: number }
}

And you can write PActions as a generic type like this:
type PActions<K extends keyof MeansArgsMap = keyof MeansArgsMap> =
  { [P in K]: { means: P, args: MeansArgsMap[P] } }[K]

Here PActions take a generic type argument corresponding to the means property. If you wanted to keep your ILine and ICurve types, you could do so from PActions:
type ILine = PActions<"line">
type ICurve = PActions<"curve">

And PActions without a type argument gets the default of keyof MeansArgsMap and evaluates to the same union PActions was in your original code.
Now Actions can be defined as a mapped type over MeansArgsMap:
type Actions = { [K in keyof MeansArgsMap]: (action: PActions<K>) => void }

And finally ResolveAction can be made generic to take a PActions<K> instead of PActions:
export function ResolveAction<K extends keyof MeansArgsMap>(
  action: PActions<K>,
): void {

  const objSwitch: Actions = {
    line: (action): void => { },
    curve: (action): void => { },
  };

  objSwitch[action.means](action); // okay
}

This compiles because now action is of type PActions<K>, so action.means is of type K.  And then objSwitch[action.means] is of type Actions[K] which is (action: PActions<K>) => void.  Now we have a single function type whose parameter is PActions<K>, and lo and behold, that's the same type as action, so the function call objSwitch[action.means](action) compiles without error.

So that's the officially recommended approach to try to keep some type safety. Obviously it's much easier to just use any or some other type loosening technique, and even the generic refactoring technique isn't perfectly safe (see ms/TS#48730). So there's a tradeoff between ease of development and type safety, and neither end of the spectrum is truly achievable. It depends on your use case and preferences as to which approach you want to take.
Playground link to code

Thank you for this explanation - if I could, I would give you more upvotes <3. I still have a question, though: Firstly, you have a "typo" when defining generic PActions - you are assigning a whole Action to args. And this rises my second question: why I cannot just set MeansArgsMap[P] as the value and have to specify means and args explicitly? type PActions<K extends keyof MeansArgsMap = keyof MeansArgsMap> =   { [P in K]: MeansArgsMap[P] }[K] And here you have a working (which doesn't rise TS error in my envirnment) example based on your solution.

I don't understand; args is MeansArgsMap[P], which is just the args, not a whole action.  The second question is similarly confusing to me; are you asking why MeansArgsMap is just a map of the args and not the whole action?

Well no, it might have been hard to understand from the example I've given but args is not an action - the whole action have also it's id: means. Have a look at the link I've added in the previous example - you should be able to understand from the example laid out there.

But there's no "typo" in my code; it's just that I started with MeansArgsMap and derived your types form them. In your link you keep your original types, then define PActionTypes, and  and then effectively compute MeansArgsMap[P] from it as PActionTypes[P]['args'].  But it's doing the same thing. Not sure why you'd want to do it your way since you're repeating means and args and line and curve multiple times, but it's really up to you. Is there some question I need to answer here? I'm confused by your confusion.

I don't think I can explain it better than I already did. Try comparing yours MeansArgsMap to my PActionTypes maybe then it will clear up a bit. Notice how differently we are assigning values to keys - where you assign args as a value and where I use ILine or ICurve. I hope should be enough to see the difference. My reason for asking this is to understand it a bit more - not to point anything out (that's why I quested typo) - and to have a complete answer.

My MeansArgsMap[P] and your PActionTypes[P]['args'] are identical, and we are therefore assigning the same things to the same places, but we are computing them differently. I see a difference in how they are expressed, but not any meaningful difference in what's happening, except that my version is less redundant than yours, while yours maintains more of the structure of your original types. But I'm not sure what you're missing or needing in terms of explanation, so I'm thinking we are at an impasse.

Actually in this case any would equal to “don't worry about it”, since ts does a good job here, handling something you know that is ok, but ts have no way to reassure it, so the solution will be to tell ts “let me take it care of it” with any.
But, a solution possible, but a bit verbose is:
export function ResolveAction(action: PActions): void {
    const objSwitch: Actions = {
        line: (action: ILine): void => {},
        curve: (action: ICurve): void => {},
    };

    if (!objSwitch[action.means]) {
        return;
    }

    switch (action.means ? action.means : "line") {
        case "line":
            objSwitch.line(action as ILine);
            break;
        case "curve":
            objSwitch.curve(action as ICurve);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}


Should have probably specified it in question but I can't accept switch as a solution :<. I need to access method ass quickly as possible and with switch it wouldn't go straight to the method but check from the top if my type matches any cases. And with this being called multiple times per seconds and having a lot of methods, I can't go with normal switch or abuse ifs.

So if you know you took care of it and you want to tell ts that you did, why not any? any workaround youll find will be any in another custom.

The problem with the behavior is clear, you have optional objects that behave differently, without if's or overriding ts you can't promise ts that it's ok. So any is basically the solution.
